# Debian dependencies for ttyecho

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

Which dependencies should a Debian package have, which distributes the binary of [`ttyecho`](http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/)?

Answer (score 1):

Build the package in a clean chroot, and add build dependencies as necessary to make the package build successfully. Some runtime dependencies will be generated automatically based on the build dependencies. After you have added the necessary build dependencies, try installing and running the resulting package in a similar clean chroot, and check if it works properly.

Tools to help you do this include `sbuild`, `schroot` and `pbuilder`, and some of the scripts from `ubuntu-dev-tools`, notably `mk-sbuild`.

if you have more specific questions on how to proceed, please comment. You may need to ask a separate question (or questions).

Comment: All of this is mostly irrelevant. The point of a clean chroot is to verify that no build dependencies have been forgotten, but it doesn't help in finding the dependencies. Debhelper is the bit that finds runtime dependencies, and for such a simple package, there are no build dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In a majority of cases, you don't need to worry about dependencies because they can be determined automatically. Install the [dh-make](http://packages.debian.org/dh-make) package and call the `dh_make` command to generate a template. There's a basic tutorial in the [Debian Administrator's Handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.building-first-package.html).

Create a directory `ttyecho-1` (package name, hyphen, version number) and put the source file there. In this directory, run `dh_make --createorig` and answer the questions. Since you're building a compiled program, you need a native, single-binary package. The `dh_make` program generates all the necessary metadata files as well as some templates for optional ones. In the generated `control` file, there is a line

```
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
```

Those `${…}` parts will be replaced by automatically-generated dependencies when the package is built. This bit of magic is performed by [`dh_shlibdeps`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dh_shlibdeps&sektion=1).

Apart from filling the parts that require human input in `debian/copyright` and `debian/control`, all you need to do for this simple package is to declare that the `ttyecho` binary needs to be installed in `/usr/bin`: create a file `debian/ttyecho.install` containing

```
ttyecho /usr/bin
```

Now run `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot` or `./debian/rules binary` and dh-make will take care of everything.